# XSLT Group and Merge

Tags: xslt

Trying to merge the following so that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Selections repeat="yes">
    <Item>
        <Title>One</Title>
        <Details repeat="yes">
            <item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </item>
            <item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </item>
        </Details>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Title>Two</Title>
        <Details repeat="yes">
            <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
        </Details>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Title>Three</Title>
        <Details repeat="yes">
            <Item>
                <Detail>Third</Detail>
            </Item>
        </Details>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Title>Three</Title>
        <Details repeat="yes">
            <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
        </Details>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Title>Four</Title>
        <Status></Status>
        <Details repeat="yes">
            <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Detail>Third</Detail>
            </Item>
        </Details>
    </Item>
</Selections>
```

becomes: (all Items/Details within any matching Title are merged)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Selections repeat="yes">
    <Item>
        <Title>One</Title>
        <Details repeat="yes">
            <item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </item>
            <item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </item>
        </Details>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Title>Two</Title>
        <Details repeat="yes">
            <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
        </Details>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Title>Three</Title>
        <Details repeat="yes">
            <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Detail>Third</Detail>
            </Item>
        </Details>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Title>Four</Title>
        <Status></Status>
        <Details repeat="yes">
            <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Detail>Third</Detail>
            </Item>
        </Details>
    </Item>
</Selections>
```

Using XSLT 2.0 but not quite getting the group-by spot on as it appears to duplicate the entries.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry forget my attempt:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Selections repeat="yes">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/Selections/Item" group-by="Title">
            <Item>
                <Title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                </Title>

                <Details repeat="yes">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group() /Details/Item"/>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Details>
            </Item>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Selections>
</xsl:template>
```

which gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Selections repeat="yes">
   <Item>
      <Title>One</Title>
      <Details repeat="yes"/>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Title>Two</Title>
      <Details repeat="yes">
         <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
         <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
      </Details>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Title>Three</Title>
      <Details repeat="yes">
         <Item>
                <Detail>Third</Detail>
            </Item>
         <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
         <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
         <Item>
                <Detail>Third</Detail>
            </Item>
         <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
         <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
      </Details>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Title>Four</Title>
      <Details repeat="yes">
         <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
         <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
         <Item>
                <Detail>Third</Detail>
            </Item>
      </Details>
   </Item>
</Selections>
```

Comment: "*not quite getting the group-by spot on as it appears to duplicate the entries.*". Show us your attempt so we can fix it, without having to write out everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/Details/Item"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

With the `xsl:for-each` you are already iterating over the `current-group()`, so effectively for each item in the group, you then copy all items in the group.

To solve, just change it to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Details/Item"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, you don't need the `xsl:for-each` at all. The existing line does the job with the need for the `xsl:for-each` too.

```
<Details repeat="yes">
   <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/Details/Item"/>
</Details>
```

Comment: Tim, thanks very much for that it seems to work well. The only issue is that the first group appears to have no content at all:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Selections repeat="yes">
   <Item>
      <Title>One</Title>
      <Details repeat="yes"/>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Title>Two</Title>
      <Details repeat="yes">
         <Item>
                <Detail>First</Detail>
            </Item>
         <Item>
                <Detail>Second</Detail>
            </Item>
      </Details>
   </Item>

Comment: XML and XSLT is case-sensitive. In the first group of Details there are only `item` elements, (note the lower case `i`), but you are selecting `Item` elements, and so nothing matches.